# Visual Studio doesn't stop on exception (assertion) at all

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a project with mostly default settings. I've tried VS2005 and VS2015, checked everything in Debug->Exceptions / Debug->Windows->Exception Settings, still no effect.
Getting the regular dialog instead of debugger stop:
[image: Getting this dialog instead of debugger stop]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckEP9.png)

Comment: What happens when you click Retry?

Comment: Paul Sanders, thank you, it actually triggered a breakpoint!